# How to do an Ajax pagination of a JSON request in the frontend with JS / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

First, I know that there is a few similar questions here but after reading probably a dozen I didn't quite find what I'm looking for, as I'm new to JS and Ajax requests.

So, let me explain what I have and what I want:

I have this small webapp doing a search on an API that returns a JSON with a maxResult of 40 items. It can be only 1 item but most of the time is more.

Right now I have everything working and appending the result in the front end, but now I want to make a pagination as 40 results are to much.

I would like to have 5 items per page, and the pages should be ajax, I don't want to reload the entire website, just page inside a container.

#### EDIT: check the final code w/o pagination here:

https://github.com/fleps/gbooks-webapp/blob/master/src/js/app.js

Ok, so, when searching I saw a few examples where after appending everything to the HTML a script ran and create the pagination by splinting the content, but I'm not sure that's the right way. Shouldn't the correct approach be to split the result on the **$.each** part and store it and append it to the HTML just when the user requests the next/n page? Wouldn't make the application lighter/faster?

Either way I don't know how to do it as I'm new on all this.

I looked a few jQuery pagination plugins but really didn't understand how to use them with my code and what's the best approach thinking about good JS practices and performance.

Btw I'm using jQuery and Bootstrap 4 UI so I would like to use the pagination UI from them if possible.

Sorry if this is too long and thank's for any help =)

Comment: Updated the original post to provide the final app.js w/o pagination, maybe make easier to someone help. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it could be :

```
const itemsPerPage = 5;
let items = null;

renderWithPagination(start, items) {
  let divs = [];
  for(var i=start; i<data.length; i++) {
    divs.push(`
      <div class="book">
      // MyHTML+ Vars
      </div>`);
    });
  }

  const prevStart = start - itemsPerPage;
  const nextStart = start + itemsPerPage;

  let pagination = '';

  if(prevStart >= 0) {
    pagination +=  `<button id="prev" data-start="${prevStart}">Previous</button>`;
  }
  if(nextStart >= 0) {
    pagination +=  `<button id="next" data-start="${nextStart}">Previous</button>`;
  }

  searchResult.innerHTML = divs.join('') + pagination;
}

...
success: function (data) {
   items = data.items;
   renderWithPagination(0, items)
}
...

$(document).click('#prev,#next', function() {
   renderWithPagination(+$(this).attr('data-start'), items);
});
```

Comment: Hey man. Thanks for replying but I really didn't understood how to use this on my code. do i remove everything inside my $.each and put on the renderWithPagination for? would i be setting my vars before the divs.push as all data is being passed there? Sorry but looks like this is changing my code a lot so I got very lost. Why I'm using push instead of append? Thanks

Comment: Sorry @BulentVural I wasn't able to work on the app to get it on github. The code is published here: https://github.com/fleps/gbooks-webapp, and you can test the app with the url provided at the top of the repository. Thanks!